# How to reload json from remote using jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a search form that loads suggestions from a remote:

```
        $form.autocomplete({
            source: Routing.generate('hn_search_suggest'),
            minLength: 2
        });
```

When I enter a word, I get exactly and only one get request with the `term` parameter. Yet if delete and/or delte the input and restart typing a new one, I would like to reload the json repsonse.

Can I configure jqueryUi autocomplete to reload its suggestion list from the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the autocomplete get its data from a controller using the Source property:

```
$("#myfield").autocomplete({
 source: function (request, response) {
     // request.term is the term searched for.
     // response is the callback function you must call to update the autocomplete's 
     // suggestion list.
     $.ajax({
         url: "/my_url/myservice.xyz",
         data: { q: request.term },
         dataType: "json",
         success: response,
         error: function () {
             response([]);
         }
     });
 });
});
```

This will callback to the server every time you type into it, reloading the source.

Comment: What is getting too less notice is that the autocomplete must be intantiated on the *input field* and not, as I did, on the form itself. Then, this ajax solution works like a charm.

Comment: I get what you mean - You can also call this whenever you want using the function itself directly, .source("", "") kinda stuff.. Theres plenty of documentation and examples about that out there. Glad it helped! @k0pernikus